# How to generalize a multiplication table for (n * m)

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiplication

I've got this:

```
def print_multiples(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        print n * i,
        i += 1
    print
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    print_multiples(i)
    i += 1
```

I need to generalize the program so that it creates a multiplication table for (n * m). In all honesty, I don't even know what it means to generalize a table in practice, though in theory I understand. I'm just not sure what integers I need to change to variables, or if that's even the route I'm supposed to take...

Comment: Hint: Currently your function produces multiplication tables for `m = 10`.

Comment: Actually, `m = n = 10`. You have two 10s in there: those are what you want to change to variables.

Comment: Could someone explain the meaning of _"generalize the program"_ ? Is it from an assignment (nothing _wrong_ with that -- just to know) ?

Comment: yes, it's an assignment. I've been messing with this for hours now and can't get it... the exact assignment is: "Please create a program that generates a 10 x 10 multiplication table.
Generalize the program to generate a multiplication table of size n x m."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your function as:

```
def print_multiples(n, m = 10):
    for i in range(0, m + 1):
        print n * i,
    print ""
```

then

```
 print_multiples(2)
```

will print

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

and

print_multiples(2, 5)

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

Then with the function:

```
def print_table(n = 10):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print_multiples(i)
```

you can:

```
 print_table()
```

and this produces the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 
...
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

while

```
 print_table(2)
```

produces:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Comment: awesome, but not quite what I need... I think... I could be very wrong, but i think he wants the program to have an output that reads:  
n * m     n+1 * m     n+2 * m 
n * m+1   n+1 * m+1   n+2 * m+1  
n * m+2   n+1 * m+2   n+2 * m+2  

or something like that....

Comment: @SydneyLing answer edited, I was completing the asnwer when you posted the comment.